# How to use querystring parameters in the databind section of ASP textbox in SPD 2007?

Tags: .net, textbox, sharepoint-2007, data-binding

I'm currently trying to find a way to dynamically set a field in a `"New Item" DataFormWebPart SPD 2007 ASPX` page which writes to an `XML` file, via a querystring passed to the page.

Ideally, it would work something like this:

Page would be opened like this:

> ../newitem.aspx?SerialNo=1234

Then within the page, the textboxes which write to a child node of `SerialNo` would create a new item under `SerialNo "1234"`

The XML schema looks something like this:

Serials

```
------Serial

         <SerialNo>1234</SerialNo>

         ------Items

               -----Item

                   <ItemName></ItemName>

                   <ItemAmount></ItemAmount>
```

Basically I'm trying to create `item` items via `TextBoxes` for `itemName` and `itemAmount`, under the appropriate `SerialNo`.

**Is it possible to do this by using a variable in the databind section of the textbox?**

i.e.

```
asp:TextBox runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','','/Serials/Serial[{$SerialNo}]/Items/Item[new]','ItemName')}" />
```